# Angles and ellipse (proof)

Tags: conic-sections

First of all, sorry for my poor English! Can you please help me? I'm trying to prove that, given a point P at an ellipse.

Please help me prove that the angles are equal.

Thanks!  [image: it's supposed to be an ellipse lol]

Comment: I drew it badly :x

Comment: Please, complete you questions. Edit it.

Comment: I'm real bad with specific math terms in English, that's why I drew it :(

Comment: What are you trying to prove? You didn't wrote. Given $P$ on an ellipse, prove what?

Comment: prove that the angles are equal

Comment: @Mariana You can edit your post to include the question in your native language at the end, and someone can translate it for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true for any point $P$. See the image:

[image]

Comment: So it must be at the vertice of the ellipse?

Comment: Note that $PO$ must be the bisectrix and the median of the triangle $F_1PF_2$.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks

Comment: I thought @MarianaCiotta was after the Reflection Property of ellipses. (A light ray emanating from one focus will bounce off the ellipse and head for the other focus.) Note the right angle marker in her diagram: this suggests (to me) that she's interested in the angle-dividing behavior of the *perpendicular to the tangent line* at $P$, not the behavior of line $OP$. In that case, it *is* true for any $P$: the perpendicular to the tangent always bisects the angle.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated the problem. You want to prove that a light ray from one focus reflects off the ellipse back to the other focus. You don't tell us what you know. Personally, I would represent the ellipse as a level set of the function 
$$f(\mathbf x) = \|\mathbf x-F_1\| + \|\mathbf x-F_2\|$$ and use the fact that $\nabla f$ is the normal vector.

You could also write down the equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
and use implicit differentiation and lots of slopes.

Comment: On second thought, maybe the OP wants it just for the one point, where it's obvious by congruent triangles?